# C++ Simple Overloading of operator+ Not Compiling

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple vector class, and I'm trying to overload the operator+ to add vectors. When it didn't work in my main program, I created a new project and stripped it down to the bare minimum, and it still didn't work.

Bare minimum code:

main.cpp

```
#include "vector3f.h"

int main()
{
    Vector3f* a = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f* b = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f* c = a + b;
}
```

vector.h

```
#ifndef __VECTOR3F_H__
#define __VECTOR3F_H__

class Vector3f
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Vector3f();
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z);
    ~Vector3f();

    Vector3f operator+(const Vector3f& rhs);
}; 

#endif
```

vector.cpp

```
#include "vector3f.h"

Vector3f::Vector3f()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}

Vector3f::Vector3f(float x, float y, float z)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}

Vector3f::~Vector3f()
{

}

Vector3f Vector3f::operator+(const Vector3f& rhs)
{
    return Vector3f(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y, z + rhs.z);
}
```

Here is the compile error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7: error: invalid operands of types 'Vector3f*' and 'Vector3f*' to binary 'operator+'
```

main.cpp line 7 is `Vector3f* c = a + b;`.

So my question, as is expected on Stack Overflow, is: what am I doing wrong?

Side note: I have a very lame IDE and the problem may be a faulty compiler, though I don't expect this to be the case.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `Vector3f* c = a + b;` should be `Vector3f c = *a + *b;`

Comment: @AndyG It didn't work, I get the same error.

Comment: notice I edited my comment to make `c` not a pointer. See my answer posted below for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dynamically allocated your Vectors, and the `+` operator is not defined for *pointers* to vectors.

So you need to change:

```
 Vector3f* a = new Vector3f();
 Vector3f* b = new Vector3f();
 //... assigning of and b
 Vector3f* c = a + b;
```

To

```
Vector3f* a = new Vector3f();
Vector3f* b = new Vector3f();
Vector3f* c = new Vector3f();
*c = *a + *b;
```

Comment: Sure, no problem :-). You may also want to define a copy constructor for your vector class so you can say `Vector3f* c = new Vector3f(*a + *b);` which may be more concise.

Comment: Why the parenthesis around the *a and *b? Point me to some website?

Comment: I know more about Java than C++, so if my question is too stupid, disregard it. :)

Comment: It's a bit overkill on my part. The parenthesis were just to make sure that `a` and `b` were de-referenced before the `+` operation. I tend to overuse parenthesis to ensure order of operations instead of just looking up precedence.

Comment: I removed the parenthesis. Operator precedence declares dereference before addition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this hasn't been said, but why are you using pointers at all?

```
Vector3f a;
Vector3f b;
Vector3f c = a + b;
```

No more trying to add pointers. No more awkward syntax. No more memory leaks.

Apart from this, you have some other things you should change:

- `__VECTOR3F_H__` is a [reserved identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).
- You should get used to using [constructor initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) (`: x(0), y(0), z(0)` and `: x(x), y(y), z(z)`) instead of assigning to data members after they've already been initialized.
- You don't need a destructor here, as one will be provided for you.
- `operator+` [should be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) using `operator+=`, which you should also provide.

Comment: Pointers are awesome, dude.

Comment: @Josh, In what way? They add extra typing in order to do anything, have unclear ownership semantics, and can easily lead to memory leaks (or double frees, or deleting a stack-allocated object, or trying to dereference an invalid pointer).

Comment: I actually don't know why I use pointers. Like I said in a previous comment, I don't know as much about C++ as I do about Java, where everything is gloriously pointer-free.

Comment: Also, thanks for the additional tips, I was hoping I would get those. :)

Comment: @Josh, Java still has "pointers". They're just called references and are garbage collected. You'd be wise to pick up some "C++ for Java Programmers" book.

Comment: Java doesn't have so much explicit pointers like C++ does. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
 Vector3f c = *a + *b;
```

Now this will overload your operator else it was an pointer addition

Comment: Now I get a different error, `cannot convert from Vector3f to Vector3f* in initialization`

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded objects not object pointers. Use this

`Vector3f c = (*a) + (*b);`

Comment: This will not work. You cannot assign a `Vector3f*` to a `Vector3f`. Lose the `*` on `c`